# find-alternate-file and move point

Tags: find-file, point

When using `find-alternate-file`, to refresh the file in the current buffer, point is always moved back to the *start* of the file.

How can I get point to be moved to where I was in the file *before* invoking `find-alternate-file`?

Comment: have you tried enabling `save-place-mode` ? Just put this somehwhere in your `.emacs` : `(save-place-mode 1)` and see if this works out for you.

Comment: You can try `revert-buffer`.

Comment: What about `auto-revert-mode`?  But I don't quite understand your use case, because when the file on disk is changed and you try to edit this buffer a warning appears anyway.